# Check if unidirected graph is a tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

I want to check if my unidirected graph is a tree. Tree is an acyclic and connected graph. I have a function that checks if graph is connected. So it is enough to be a tree if graph is connected and |E|=|V|-1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, `E = V - 1` is sufficient to check that your graph is a tree.

The logic is that every tree begins with just a root note (`V=1`, `E=0`, so `E=V-1`), and from there, any time we add one node (`V=V+1`), we must also add exactly one edge (`E=E+1`). This makes the equation `E=V-1` remain true for all trees.

A cycle occurs when we connect two existing nodes with a new edge (`E=E+1` but `V` stays the same), rendering the equation `E=V-1` false.

If it interests you, you may want to read about the more general formula `v - e + f = 2`, where `f` is the number of regions inside a graph, including the exterior region. (A tree only has an exterior region so `f=1`). This rule is called Euler's Formula, which you can read about [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula).

Answer (score 2):

**Connected:** 
It means that for every pair of vertices you choose, there will always be a path between them.
**|E|=|V|-1:** 
if your graph has |V| vertices and you are given |E|=|V|-1 edges to connect them, then if you form a cycle, you won't be able to form a connected graph (some vertices will remain without edges). 
 We can conclude that these conditions are enough.